# Initialize objects of Associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have three models which have been defined as follows:

**Answer Sheet**

```
class AnswerSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :answer_sections
     accepts_nested_attributes for :answer_sections
end
```

**Answer Section**

```
class AnswerSection < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :answer_sheet
     has_many :answers
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

**Answers**

```
class Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: answer_section
end
```

I also have the following method defined in the `AnswerSheet` model

```
def self.build_with_answer_sections
    answer_sheet = new  # new should be called on the class e.g. AnswerSheet.new
    4.times do |n|
        answer_sheet.answer_sections.build
    end
answer_sheet
end
```

How would I go about making it so that when I make a new instance of the the AnswerSheet, I can also generate all it's dependent models as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [after_initialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback

```
    class AnswerSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :answer_sections
      accepts_nested_attributes for :answer_sections
      after_initialize :add_answer_section

      def add_answer_section
        4.times {self.answer_sections.build }
      end
     end

    class AnswerSection < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :answer_sheet
      has_many :answers
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

      after_initialize :add_answer

     def add_answer
       2.times {self.answers.build}
     end
 end
```

Comment: oh that's interesting! i wasn't aware such a thing existed. Based on this, would I be correct in saying that if i added that I could add the callback into the answer_section and that would create all my answers as well?

Comment: Yes you can, Updated the answer with it.. so now u create `AnswerSheet.new` you will get 4 answer_sections with each answersheet object and each answersection object will have 2 answers.. cheers!

Comment: note that if you use a model that has only a `belongs_to` association (to the model _Post_ for example) the `self.post` attribute will not exists yet at initialization time, and you need to use `self.build_post`. see [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)